# Web container for jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Is Tomcat still the go to container?
What other open source, convention over configuration, non yak shaving, easy to use options are out there?

Comment: You could try using JBoss, which actually has a special version of Tomcat inside of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the purpose?

You got Jetty, Glassfish, Tomcat, ...

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Servlet_containers